# Aligning 2 columns with images in rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want to align col-lg-8 with col-lg-4 that contains 2 rows for 2 images, i need those 2 columns align perfectly so they fit each others height

i tried this: 
[desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hxGj.jpg)

[and what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK6Uk.jpg)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
         <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg"/>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg"/>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMpZOB)

Comment: The Columns are the same height in your example. Are you instead trying to have the image in the col-lg-8 column match the height of the container?

Comment: They are over lapping col 4 is going over col 8

Comment: The images on your photobucket are not showing in your codepen example. Can't see the issue you are describing.

Comment: i've changed description for post, check it out, i putted images of desired and what i got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that you can't depend on Bootstrap to do everything, you don't need any of the additional css "gymnastics" proposed by @derek-gutierrez because with native Bootstrap classes alone you can get done *almost* everything and most certainly in this particular case here.

The following code is leaner and does everything you want with native Bootstrap classes alone. No extra gymnastics needed. All with perfect paddings/gutter out of the box:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <img src="Cupcakes01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="Cupcakes01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="Cupcakes01.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's the magic of the Bootstrap grid just working.

Notice: You had 2 unnecessary divs (first row and col-lg-12). I cut them out. That was totally useless fat in your code. Don't put in more code than necessary. That reduces the number of potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, I hope this is what you are looking for

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg"/>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't depend on bootstrap to do everything. You are going to add some of your own custom CSS to achieve the effect you want. If you are unfamiliar with css and selectors [W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is a good resource.

**To achieve this effect add this CSS to the head of your document:**
(This is simply to illustrate based off of your example, you will want to be more specific with your selectors if there is going to be more to this page)

```
<style>
    img {
        width: 100%; /* Makes imgs match the parent column/container width */
    }
    #top-image {
        margin-bottom: 30px; /* Adds the necessary space to the bottom of the first image */
    }
</style>
```

The columns inside the col-lg-4 should not be col-lg-2. This is basically saying these columns are 2/12ths the size of the container. Instead change them to 12 to span the full width of the container. I also added an id to the first image in this column "id="top-image" to add the necessary margin.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <img src="img/1.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div id="top-image" class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <img src="img/2.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <img src="img/3.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```